# Import 500 GB of Data into Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I want to import a 500 GB dataset into Power BI, but Power BI is limited 1 GB. How can I get the data into Power BI?

Thanks.

Comment: Chop your dataset into 500 sets, each of 1GB instead of 1 set of 500GB.

Answer (score 3):

For 500GB I'd definitely recommend Direct Query mode (as Joe recommends) or a [live connection to a SSAS cube](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-data#live-connections-and-directquery-to-on-premises-data-sources). In these scenarios, the data model is hosted in a separate location (such as a database server) and Power BI sends its queries to that location and displays the returned results.

However, I'll add that the 1GB limit is the limit after compression. (Meaning you can fit more than 1GB of uncompressed data into the advertised 1GB dataset limit.)

While it would be incredibly difficult to reduce a 500GB dataset to 1GB (even with compression), there are things you can do once you understand how the compression works in Power BI.

In Power BI, compression is done by columns, not rows. So a column that has 800 million rows with identical values can see significant compression. Likewise, a column with a different value in every row cannot be compressed much at all.

Therefore:

1. Do not import columns you do not absolutely need for analysis (particularly identity columns, GUIDs, free-form text fields, or binary data such as images)
2. Look at columns with a high degree of variability and see if you can also eliminate them.
3. Reduce the variability of a column where possible. E.g. if you only need a date & not a time, do not import the time. If you only need the whole number, do not import 7 decimal places.
4. Bring in less rows. If you cannot eliminate high-variability columns, then importing 1 year of data instead of 17 (for example) will also reduce the data model size.

Marco Russo & the SQLBI team have a number of good resources for further optimizing the size of a data model (SSAS tabular, Power Pivot & Power BI all use the same underlying modelling engine). For example: [Optimizing Multi-Billion Row Tables in Tabular](https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/optimizing-multi-billion-row-tables-in-tabular/)

Answer (score 1):

If possible given your source data, you could use Direct Query mode. The 1 GB limit does not apply to Direct Query. There are some limitations to Direct Query mode, so check the documentation to make sure that it will meet your needs.

Some documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-use-directquery).

Answer (score 0):

1) make Aggregation on data on sql side __reduce size 
2) import only useful column____________reduce size